# Change background color of programmatically created radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, background-color, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I used various method but I couldn't find a way to change color of a `RadioButton` that's created programmatically. 
         Is there any other way than using a background Image? 
         with `minSDKVersion` is `21`.   The below way  I'm creating my `RadioButton`.

`RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(co);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change `RadioButton` button color programmatically use this.
because your `minSdk is 21`.  You can use `setButtonTintList` this way.

```
RadioButton raPrivate = new RadioButton(co);
int textColor = Color.parseColor(#000000);
raPrivate.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));
```

Comment: `RadioButton raPrivate = new RadioButton(co); `  This is how I'm creating my radioButton.

Comment: @qwerty glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to change background color of Radio Button:

```
 radioButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```